# How to test proxy if its working and send mail if isnt

Tags: linux, shell-script, wget, proxy

i need a script that will test if proxy is working or not. Scipt should download a page with wget then grep for specific string of characters. If it can't find the string then it should send a email to specific address. I am having problems with part where it should decide if it found the string or not. 
    export http_proxy='http://proxy.test.cz:1234/'

```
wget -nvq --proxy-user=test --proxy-password=test google.com &>/dev/null | grep -q '<H1>you cant't use internet</H1>' || ( echo "Proxy isnt't working" | mail -s "Proxy isnt't working!!!" -r "No-reply<no-reply@test.cz>" test@test.cz )
```

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel.  There are many programs that can monitor various aspects of a system and send you alerts when services go down.  One such program that comes to mind is [monit](https://mmonit.com/monit/), but there are many others.

Comment: Boss said to do it this way so i dont have choice. Also proble is that the proxy is working all the time just sometimes it allows to visit intnertet for all users.

Comment: Your boss is a manager. You're a technicial (presumably). Suggest a better technical solution that still solves the problem.

Comment: That is true, but i also dont want  to study another think right now. I have a lot of work and i dont have time for reading manuals.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
wget -q --spider ${URL}
if [ $? = 0 ]
then
    STATUS="UP"
else
  STATUS="DOWN"
fi
echo $STATUS
```

Send mail based on the status value.

Comment: Thanks for help. I also need it to work without creating a index.html file and to grep that specific string : <H1>You cant use intrenet</H1>.

Comment: Didn't really understand you.You don't want to create a html file and grep the heading? from where?

Comment: I am sorry if it is confusing. If you look at this code : wget -nvq --proxy-user=test --proxy-password=test google.com &>/dev/null | grep -q '<H1>you cant't use internet</H1>'  it does exectly what i need. I just need to somehow repair my whole code that it will decide correctly. Now it just sends mails even if it finds the string.

Comment: My bad sorry, now i see that wget --spider just looks if the page exists and dont download it.